# Symbols for four and five vertical dots

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

I am very new to latex, but have spent hours trying without success to figure this out.  I need symbols for both 4 and 5 vertically stacked dots.  I know the commands for 1 dot (`\cdot`), and 3 dots (`\vdots`).  It seems like one methods that I've read about here is to combine symbols, for example combining 4 single dots to create a 4 vertical dot symbol.  But, I can't figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can always look at the definition of `\vdots` and see if you can tweak it to give you 4 or 5 dots.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. For now you can use the 3 dot version to show it, but depending on exactly how you intended to use this there may be alternate solutions.

Comment: Something that might be helpful: when you type `texdef vdots` from the command line, the output is: `macro:->\vbox {\baselineskip 4\p@ \lineskiplimit \z@ \kern 6\p@ \hbox {.}\hbox {.}\hbox {.}}`. Perhaps this will help you or someone else as a starting point :) Welcome!

Comment: Could you tell in what context you would like to use these four/five vertical dots?

Comment: This is for a data summary report that contains a large number of tables with data means.  We have been ask to provide a rough measure of variability (coefficient of variation or CV) next to each number in each table.  The number of vertical dots next to the number will indicate a discrete range of the CV.  For example, 1 dot may mean the CV is between 0 and 0.5, 2 dots .5-1, 3 dots 1-1.5, 4 dots 1.5-2, 5 dots greater than 2.  The idea to to provide a general sense of the CV (is it large or small) without cluttering up the report with the actual CV values.

Comment: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html could be useful when you search for a specific symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way.  The gap is controlled by the `\setstackgap` macro; The whole thing can be raised or lowered with a `\raisebox`;  the number of dots in the stack are the space-separated argument of the stack.

Note:  you could stack any characters as such, not just dots.  If the `[usestackEOL]` option is passed to the package, the EOL separator is no longer a space, but a `\\` character.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
%\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\begin{document}
$A \Shortstack{. . . .}B$
$A \raisebox{-1.2pt}{\Shortstack{. . . . .}}B$
$A \setstackgap{S}{.5pt}\Shortstack{. . . . .}B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option, editing the definition of the original `\vdots`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\def\fourvdots{\vbox{\baselineskip1\p@ \lineskiplimit\z@
  \kern6\p@\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$ a \vdots a \fourvdots a $
\end{document}
```

Changing the `1` in `\baselineskip1\p@` you control the spacing.

[image]

Comment: The `\kern 6\p@` at the top of `\vdots` is intended to give a little extra space above it when used in a matrix of other array. You would not want it if this is to be used as a mathematical symbol, whether it is a binary operator, a relation or whatever. I've seen this question somewhere before; I can't recall where, but I do remember the symbol was some kind of relation or binary operation.